# How to make an image not scroll?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to make an image not scroll with the rest of the page. However, I want the image to be a certain percentage of width, and the browser automatically figure out the heightto display the image, and the image height automatically configured also determines the parent div's height.

The following code allows me to position the image area nicely and size the actual image nicely:

```css
.popPictureParent {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.popPicture {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.popPicture img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="popPictureParent" id="picture1">
  <div class="popPicture">
    <img src="./files/painting_scene_smaller.png" alt="painting scene" />
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I make the image not sccroll similar to this website: https://www.thediyjoint.com/ but have the image size and position the divs how I have it right now? I have other things on the website that it has to not intrude, this isn't the only thing, so.

I've tried the background image thing, using fixed, absolute, but neither work. I need the browser to do some math to make the image look nice based on a width percentage given.

When I try the background, there isn't an option to set the parent's div width to what the background needs. This is really convoluted to me. If more information is needed, please comment.

EDIT: the thing is, I need the image to serve as a width and height placeholder, so the parent div sizes to it. The background image doesn't give a placeholder. Also, I need the image to not show up outside of its parent div.

Comment: Don't use `<img>`  try using `background-image`, `background-sizing` and `background-attachment`

Comment: Please ask Google first.
I found it in first attempt.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
.popPicture{
     background-image: url('./files/painting_scene_smaller.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the **background-attachment property**

> **fixed** This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to
>   the viewport. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism, a ‘fixed’
>   background doesn't move with the element.

Instead of adding the img tag to the HTML, use CSS to add background-image to the wrapper class in this case .popPicture

For example:

```
.popPicture{
     background-image: url('/files/painting_scene_smaller.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

You can read more about this property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Additionally, depending on your use case you can adjust the background-size property

> The background-size CSS property specifies the size of the background
>   images. The size of the image can be fully constrained or only
>   partially in order to preserve its intrinsic ratio.